# Consulta MySQL Select

Tags: javafx, mysql-workbench

**Antes que nada buenas tardes a todos.
Al grano!!**

Tengo una tabla llamada "control" en la cual llevo registrado los kilometrajes de varios vehiculos todo bien a la hora de insertar eliminar etc.

Pero estoy tratando de traer los datos de un vehiculo determinado por su matricula; este dato lo nombre **"KmRest"** o sea **(Kilometraje Restante)**. por ejemplo les explico como funciona la cuestion:
Tengo los siguientes campos: **KmInicial, KmFinal, KmReco, ProxMantenimiento y KmRest**
el proceso es el siguiente:
KmInicial = 100
KmFinal = 200
KmReco = 100 (La diferencia entre KmInicial y KmFinal)
ProxMantenimiento = 5000
KmRest = 5000 - 100
KmRest = 4900

Hasta aqui todo va bien pero al seguir introduciendo datos el KmRest llegara a "0" cuando esto sucede mi programacion indicara que es hora de un mantenimiento **PERO!**  tengo una consulta SQL que me arroja el **"KmRest"** del ultimo insert de esta manera :`"SELECT min(kmrest) AS Restantes from control WHERE matricula = ? order by max(fecha)"`

esto me funciona hasta cierto punto pero cuando vuelvo a restar para mostrar el KmRest este no me trae el nuevo y ultimo valor sino el anterior aqui un ejemplo:
[image: Lo subrayado en amarillo es el dato que DEBERIA mostrar pero lo que obtengo es el anterior a este.]

Aqui esta mi tabla en mi programacion mostrando el dato que no debe ser:
[image: Y pues no se como realizar la consulta en el mysql]

si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradezco es para un proyecto de la Universidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De donde sacas `Matricula` no lo sé, hasta donde yo veo el campo es placa.
y esta consulta te debe funcionar

```
SELECT kmrest FROM control WHERE placa = '?' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

La verdad no me acuerdo si `LIMIT` va después del `ORDER BY` o antes en MYSQL, pruebas y comentas profa.

Saludos

Comment: matricula es placa he puesto matricula solo por costumbre

Comment: Y te funciono el query?

Comment: Esta me funciono voy a hacer unas pruebas con mas datos te estare avisando si surge algo mal y muchas gracias fue de gran ayuda! PD. solo tube que cambiar la posicion del LIMIT

Comment: Marcala cómo respuesta si te sirvió.

Comment: Dalo por hecho!